# Программное отключение экрана в android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-broadcastreceiver

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при ответе на входящий звонок отключался экран

Использую PoweManager :

```
 public void turnOffScreen(){
    // turn off screen
    Log.v("ProximityActivity", "OFF!");
    mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
}
```

Ниже весь класс:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {
private PowerManager mPowerManager;
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    final PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state)
            {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Call Ended..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("stop", "Call Ended....");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Call Picked..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
                    Log.i("received", "Call Picked....");
                    startRecording(incomingNumber);
                    //turnOffScreen();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // Вот здесь надо обрабатывать звонок
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Call RingingBEOCH..." + incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   autoPickCall(context);
                    /*try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
                                Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }*/
                    break;
            }

        }
    };
    telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

При ответе на звонок приложение крашится 
Логи:

```
11-16 06:02:17.674 20512-20512/com.phonedialer.phonedialer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.phonedialer.phonedialer, PID: 20512
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock android.os.PowerManager.newWakeLock(int, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.test.myapplication.CallReceiver.turnOffScreen(CallReceiver.java:114)
    at com.test.myapplication.CallReceiver$1.onCallStateChanged(CallReceiver.java:43)
    at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:291)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:921)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:716)
```

Где ошибка может быть?`

Answer (score 2):

В коде Вы нигде не инициализируете объект `mPowerManager`, поэтому при вызове `mPowerManager.newWakeLock(...)` получаете `NullPointerException`.

Перед вызовом метода `turnOffScreen()` получите инстанс `PowerManager`:

```
mPowerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: ошибка в логах исчезла
но экран не отключается все равно

Comment: @sqlbastard1613, Создайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: но зачем дублировать этот
по сути вопрос в шапке